# Error When creating an Application class in Android

Tags: android, debugging

I followed the advice given on the internet regarding working with Application classes in android.
I also added a field "android:name=.Session" to my Application object in the manifest.

The application is called "Session".

What do you think is the error? This is happening even before the my App starts.

This is the error stack:

```
**java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.appfire.Session: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.appfire.Session**
 at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.makeApplication(ActivityThread.java:523)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3996)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2900(ActivityThread.java:119)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1901)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 **Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.appfire.Session**
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1479)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:957)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:942)
at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.makeApplication(ActivityThread.java:518)
```

Comment: Can you post your Session class?  Does the constructor use invalid arguments?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your Session class is public, is not static, and does not have a default constructor.

```
public class Session extends Application {}
```

Comment: Hmm.. Yes here is how I defined my class: public class Session extends Application {}

Comment: Ok. Problem solved.

**I was missing a constructor in my Application class. It is important to have one.**

Answer (score 0):

In the Manifest application tag, make sure you include the fully-qualified class name of your custom Application object:

```
<application
    android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.Session"
    ....  />
```

The Android docs do say the class name must be fully qualified:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#nm

(This is not the case for `Activity` class names that are included in the `activity` tag of the Manifest.  Those *can* be relative, preceded with a '.').

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to delete the whole project from Eclipse and load it again from SVN. Now it works